# How to find missing sequence number which is minimum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table which has sequence number.

I want to find the missing sequence number which is minimum out of missing numbers.

```
For eg.,

Seq No: 1,2,3,5,7,9 ==> Expected result: 4
Seq No: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,15 ==> Expected result: 8
```

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
select seq,seq-row_number() over(order by seq) as diff
from tablename
)
select * from cte where diff<>0 and diff in (select min(diff) from cte where diff<>0)
```

Answer (score 2):

make use of `row_number()` to generate a new sequence and compare that with your original seq

```
select  min(new_seq)
from
(
    select  *, new_seq = row_number() over (order by seq)
    from    your_table
) t
where   seq <> new_seq
```

Comment: `TOP(1)` with appropriate `ORDER BY` may work faster than `MIN` in this case

Answer (score 2):

Select the minimum sequence number where the sequence number plus one does not exist and add one:

```
select min(seqNo)+1 from SeqNoTable where seqNo+1 not in (select SeqNo from SeqNoTable)
```